# How to know what method I used in eap.conf

Tags: freeradius

above is my eap.conf file, I want to know if i use this eap.conf, how can I know which EAP method I used, EAP-TLS, EAP-PEAP or EAP-TTLS.
As I know EAP-TLS only used certificates and EAP-PEAP or EAP-TTLS only use user name, password. But on my freeradius server it need both user name, password and certificates in my Wi-Fi module to connect my AP.
I'm a newer on freeradius

Comment: I don't know how to add my eap.conf file and my freeradius debug log

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi zhangxiaozhong, you could add them using pastebin links.  You probably only want to include the relevant lines.

I'm not really sure what you're asking in the rest of your question.  What do you want to do and what's not working?